# Require to select all error message from sp in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
ALTER PROC usp_test 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @errorMsg NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    CREATE TABLE #tmp (id TINYINT)

    INSERT INTO #tmp (id)
    SELECT 1666555666666

    SET @errorMsg =@errorMsg + ISNULL(ERROR_MESSAGE(),'')

    INSERT INTO #tmp (id)
    SELECT 1

    SET @errorMsg =@errorMsg + ISNULL(ERROR_MESSAGE(),'')

    INSERT INTO #tmp (id)
    SELECT 'a'

    SET @errorMsg =@errorMsg + ISNULL(ERROR_MESSAGE(),'')

    SELECT @errorMsg
END
```

Above is my sp and its giving two error and i need to select all error message.
Please guide me for same.

Note: Write now its giving two error but it can be of any number.
This is just sample sp

Comment: You would get an error message along with an exception.  You need `try`/`catch` blocks.

Comment: If i will use try catch then it will not give both error.

Comment: You can write a procedure which will store the generated exception in a error table. That procedure you can call in catch block, So whenever catch block encounters, It will insert a exception in a table. This approach may help you

Comment: @Shaili - IF i will use try catch then it will not give all error

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
ALTER  PROC usp_test 
AS
BEGIN TRAN
    DECLARE @errorMsg NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    CREATE TABLE #tmp (id TINYINT)
    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO #tmp (id)
        SELECT 1666555666666
    END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
        SET @errorMsg =@errorMsg + ISNULL(' - '+ERROR_MESSAGE(),'')
    END CATCH

    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO #tmp (id)
        SELECT 1
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @errorMsg =@errorMsg  +ISNULL(' - '+ ERROR_MESSAGE(),'')
    END CATCH

    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO #tmp (id)
        SELECT 'a'
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @errorMsg =@errorMsg  +ISNULL(' - '+ ERROR_MESSAGE(),'')
    END CATCH

    IF  @errorMsg=''
    COMMIT TRAN

    IF  @errorMsg<>''
    BEGIN
    SELECT @errorMsg
    ROLLBACK TRAN
END
GO
```

Comment: For above logic i have to write try and catch for nth number of time

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @msg VARCHAR(max); 

    BEGIN try 
        SELECT 1 / 0; 
    END try 

    BEGIN catch 
        CREATE TABLE #temp 
          ( 
             err VARCHAR(100) 
          ); 

        INSERT INTO #temp 
        SELECT Error_message() AS ErrorMessage; 

        SET @msg= (SELECT err 
                   FROM   #temp) 

        PRINT @msg 
    END catch 
END
```